# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: WorkflowScript

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I Have created multibranch pipeline(declarative) and placed jenkinsfile in bitbucket repo. hooks configured to trigger build in pipeline. when developer commits code pipeline it's throwing following error.

[Bitbucket] Build result notified
**groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: WorkflowScript**
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getProperty(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:458)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$6.call(Checker.java:293)

When I checked the build **groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: any for class: WorkflowScript** error occurred. when I tried to build the job in **replay** mode I have notified red space in the beginning of the pipeline script. I have removed the red space and it worked.

[jenkinsfile view in "reply" mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5Lvs.png)

[Jenkinsfile in bitbucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oja2W.png)

the pipeline structure I used is

```
 pipeline {
   agent any
     options {....}
   stages {...}
}
```

please help me how to eradicate the issue...

Comment: please share the failed stage code, so that we can help to find out what's wrong. It's better to share the entire Jenkinsfile (don't use screenshot to showing code)

Comment: You might want to recheck the pipeline syntax again & try running your jenkinsfile directly from the configure section.

Comment: Could be an invisible character in the Jenkinsfile? Try to delete and rewrite the file (no copy&paste).

Answer (score 9):

The `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException` error usually means that Jenkins is not able to find a variable or command used.

In this case, the error message says `No such property: **any** for class: WorkflowScript`.

Therefore, it looks like Jenkins is not able to find `any`.

I believe in a declarative pipeline, `agent any` is valid. Are you using `any` in another place in the script?

You did not provide the full script, so I could not see where the problem is.